# What is the correct iOS code for Google Sign-in

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-signin

I recently updated my GoogleSignin pod from 3.x to 4.1.1 and the docs linked from here:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk/

which go to here:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in

are out of date.

1. They say the import is:

`#import <Google/SignIn.h>`

2. They have some setup code:

   ```
    NSError* configureError;
    [[GGLContext sharedInstance] configureWithError: &configureError];
    NSAssert(!configureError, @"Error configuring Google services: %@", configureError);
   ```

That seems to be out of date.

I could not find 4.1.x specific docs.

(I mean this question mostly as a way to get Google Identity to update the docs.  I know the answer, which I will post below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bellow code for Pod file

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.2'
use_frameworks!

target ’App Target’ do
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
end
```

Then into AppDelegate.swift file add Header **import GoogleSignIn**
Then
 `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool { GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "googlesigninclient id";
}`

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: 
[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                             sourceApplication: 
 options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? 
String,
                                                annotation: 
 options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
}
```

Now in ViewController class

```
class LoginViewController:UIViewController 
,GIDSignInUIDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate { 

  //Add Button action for gmail login 
 @IBAction func loginWithGmail(_ sender: Any) {

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()


}


 //deleage method will call after gmail login 
 func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, 
 withError error: Error!) {
     if (error == nil) {//login success
     } else {
      //login fail
     }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Luckily, the github example repo is maintained. According to this commit:

https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/commit/39c243954be0e730963f79720265839f1c0b6deb

The correct import is:

`#import <GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h>`

(or use `@import GoogleSignIn` if you want)

`GGLContext` seems to have been removed, so the code that uses it should be removed.  There doesn't seem to be some other equivalent that needs to be put in its place.

With these two changes, Google signin worked for me.